# How do I change the color of the menu bar for a specific page in Android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, user-interface

In my app, I have the menu bar set for one color on the home screen, but my app would look a lot better if it could be a different color on different screens. What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score -1):

Search in your project directory for app>res>values>colors.xml . Once you open the file search for "ColorPrimary" and a code with the likes of "#e65100". That code represents the color for you app bar, and one way you can change is to visit: https://material-ui.com/style/color/ and copy the code for your color of choice. The other way is to click on the small rectangle on the left and a color picker should pop up. To use different color for each activity, I'd suggest to edit that color code through java code each time the activity is started. I hope that helps.